# How to reset the link when using document.location.hash?

Tags: javascript, html

I able to scroll to a particular DIV of interest when using document.location.hash.  However, when I refresh the page I am unable to get this scrolling to the same DIV.

JS

```
 document.location.hash = 'sendEmailWrap';
```

Link:

```
 myDomain.com/publication.php?article=658#sendEmailWrap
```

When I refresh the page the '#sendEmailWrap' persists at the end of the link, as a result the scroll to the same DIV does not work.  How do I go about getting the link back to

```
 myDomain.com/publication.php?article=658
```

Comment: When the document is unloading, you can remove the hash values from the document location.

Comment: please can you elaborate?

Comment: check this out.. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp you can bind a onunload event.

Comment: How would you go about removing the hash value from the end of a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not working due to your content not being rendered yet when the page loads, you could "reset" the hash after the content is ready. You could try:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var hash = location.hash;
    location.hash = '';
    location.hash = hash;
};
```

or, to simply get rid of it when the page is loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
    location.hash = '';
};
```